# Problem with the usage of <Routes>, <Route> and <Navigate> in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm very confused with the change of usage of react-router-dom v6. By their documentation, we can simply pass our Route component inside the element prop, but I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: meta.relativePath.startsWith is not a function
```

and I couldn't find any solutions.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Results } from './Results';

export const Catogories = () => {
    return (
        <div className='p-4'>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path='/' element={<Navigate to='/search' />} />
                <Route exact path={["/search", '/images,', '/news', '/videos']} element={<Results />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `path` prop can only be a string, arrays are no longer used so you must explicitly render a route for each.

[Routes and Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> ```
> declare function Route(
>   props: RouteProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactElement | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string; // <-- string type only, no string[]
> }
> ```

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<Navigate to='/search' replace />} />
  <Route path='/search' element={<Results />} />
  <Route path='/images' element={<Results />} />
  <Route path='/news' element={<Results />} />
  <Route path='/videos' element={<Results />} />
</Routes>
```